# how to place checkbox side by side using j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

We are developing a mobile application. We want to place multiple checkbox side by side for multiselection purpose.

Tried searching different solutions on various blogs, unable to find it.

I tried the following code:

```
 public Student_Att_App() {
  form = new Form("Technologies");
  technology = new ChoiceGroup("Select Technology Which You Know",Choice.MULTIPLE);
  exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
  choose = new Command("Choose", Command.SCREEN, 2);  
  }

  public void startApp() {
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  technology.append("1", null);
  technology.append("2", null);
  technology.append("3", null);
  technology.append("4", null); 

  index = form.append(technology);
```

but it gives the multiple checkbox one below the other and I need it side by side.

Comment: did you check instructions on how to get desired layout of items? given your code snippet it looks like you didn't. It is provided in [lcdui Form API docs, section Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html#layout)